# Is there a way to write Jekyll posts without the date?

Tags: jekyll

Is there a way to have files named `title.MARKUP` instead of `YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP`? I'm not writing blog posts so it's not very useful to add the date in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to write posts - you can make pages instead. Anything not in the _posts directory is considered a page (or a collection if you are using that). Name it however you like. If it is in the _posts directory it is supposed to include the date.

I ignore the _posts directory on a couple of my sites - everything is a page instead.

You can use markdown in pages or posts, jekyll doesn't care.